# Palindrome Index HackerRank JS

Tags: javascript

I am currently trying to solve the HackerRank Palindrome Index challenge. https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/palindrome-index/problem

My function seems to be returning "undefined" instead of the solution (the index that should be changed for the string to become a palindrome. Why?

```js
function palindromeIndex(s) {
    // Write your code here
    const reverse = (string) => s.split("").reverse().join("");
    var reversed = reverse(s);
    if (reversed === s) {
        return -1;
    } else {
        for (let i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
            // splice the array to remove index i and then compare 
            let myArray = s.split("");
            if ((myArray.splice(i, 1).join("")) === reverse(myArray.splice(i, 1).join(""))) {
                return i;
            } 
        } ;
    }

}

console.log(palindromeIndex("racezcar"));
```

Comment: Please provide some test data and the *expected* and the *actual* output to make the question self contained and not to rely on an external resource which you need to create an extra an account to see. But obviously this function is only returing a value if a very specific condition is met.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your `reverse` function is always operating on the same input parameter `s` to the function, because the local parameter of the reverse function would be called `string`. Thus, whenever you are calling `reverse(something)` you are getting back the original input reversed.
2. You seem to have a misunderstanding on how [`Array.splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) works.

   - it works *in place*  ie modifies the array you call it on
   - it returns the *removed elements* and not the modified array

   In your case, it seems easier to use `substr` instead of splice ...

```js
function palindromeIndex(s) {
    // Write your code here
  const reverse = (string) => string.split("").reverse().join("");
  if (s === reverse(s)) {
    return -1;
  } else {
    for (let i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
      let spliced = s.substr(0, i) + s.substr(i+1);
      if (spliced === reverse(spliced))
        return i;
      }
  }

  //return whatever specified, when the input can't be
  //converted into a palindrome ... 
}

console.log(palindromeIndex("racezcar"));
console.log(palindromeIndex("racezcars"));
```

This code still returns `undefined` when there is no way to turn the input into a palindrome,

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I'm a beginner so I really appreciate your input :)

Answer (score 0):

The reason your function is returning `undefined` is due to your `reverse` function. There is a minor mistake where you call `s` instead of `string`:

```js
const reverse = (string) => s.split("").reverse().join("");
```

should be changed to:

```js
const reverse = (string) => string.split("").reverse().join("");
```

Otherwise, you still have a bit of work to do to get it working as expected.

Comment: That's only one of the errors. The other one is the wrong use of `Array.splice` ...

Comment: Right, but the question is only referring to *why the output is undefined*.

Comment: Yes, and the output is also wrong because the wrong parts of the string are compared to each other (due to the wrong use of splice)...